# WPF: How to remove the focused animation of a togglebutton?

Tags: wpf, animation, focus, togglebutton

I have some toggle buttons in a listbox. When I uncheck a toggle button, an animation is run on the button, making him "blink" from grey to blue constantly.

How could I stop this animation from being played, so that it stays gray, even while it is focused?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Comment: are you using defaul togglebutton style?

Comment: Have you tried copying the styles in Expression Blend?

Comment: Yes I am using the default togglebutton style. And I've tried within Blend, but without any success for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own template without a ButtomChrome element in it.

Comment: So I have to manually rewrite all the styles? Including MouseHover / MouseDown and so on?

Comment: Yes, this is a hard coded behavior of the button chrome, so you need to either use all of it, or nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure whether this is a good solution, but for me it sufficed to set `Focusable = false`.

Comment: I have been searching for a quick and dirty way to do this.  This is much nicer instead of editing the templates.